# Grabbing image with cURL php

Tags: php, image, curl, upload, save

Trying to save image to my server using cURL.  The image appears to download.  It shows the correct bytes but when i link image does not work.  I then DL to see and nope its a blank image.

here is my code... whats the issue with it?

```
$ch = curl_init("'. $image .'");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$fp = fopen("$rename.jpg",'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata); 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Try using true and false instead of 0 and 1.  I don't _think_ that will make a difference, but it might.  Also, what happens if you do a var_export(strlen($rawdata)) after your curl_close($ch) statement?  I'm just trying to figure out if the issue is with the image retrieval or the storing of it afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I test your script it work fine for me, just remove the useless double quote and dot for $image.

```
<?
$image ="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5";
$rename="123";

$ch = curl_init($image);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$fp = fopen("$rename.jpg",'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata); 
fclose($fp);
?>
```